# How to manage dependencies in a cljs macro?

Tags: clojure, macros, clojurescript

Say I have a macro in the clj file to be used in a cljs file

```
(defmacro defelem [name element]
  `(defcard ~name
     (ct.react/react-card
      (r/as-element
       [~element]
       )
      )
     )
  )
```

and the dependencies are ct.react and r. Should the dependencies be required in the clj or the cljs files? I tried both but neither worked.

I get the error in shadow:

```
(defelem cart-card cart)
-------^------------------------------------------------------------------------
Use of undeclared Var myapp.workspaces.cards/react-card
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why would that be?

Answer (score 1):

Vars named by fully-qualified symbols are not required to exist when a `defmacro` is compiled. This means you can write them directly in your macro, and it'll work, as long as the vars that are referenced will exist at runtime:

```
(defmacro defelem [name element]
  `(defcard ~name
     (package.cljs.ns/react-card
      (r/as-element [~element]))))
```

Of course, this means that the compiler can't protect you if you attempt to reference a var that doesn't exist, so you need to be a little more careful than usual.

See related question: [How do I deal with required Clojurescript code from Clojurescript macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781868/how-do-i-deal-with-required-clojurescript-code-from-clojurescript-macros)

Since you're using shadow-cljs, also see [its own documentation](https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2019/10/12/clojurescript-macros.html) on the matter:

> Since the macros run in CLJ and not CLJS the namespace aliases you configured in CLJS will not work in the macro. It is recommended to use fully qualified names if you need to access code from other namespaces.